# How to extract image filename from UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have  `<UIImage: 0x6040000b9800> , {1668, 2500`} name for taken photo from gallery. But I need imagename in String. Anyone help me to solve in swift 4? I have given codes below:

```
extension PhotoViewController: ImagePickerDelegate {
func wrapperDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {

}

func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
    self.image = images[0]



    let navigati:PhotoDescriptorController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.PhotoDescriptorController) as! PhotoDescriptorController

    navigati.imageDest = self.image
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigati, animated: true)

    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func cancelButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what research you've undertaken, you've already tried, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: What is `ImagePickerController`?

Comment: `ImagePickerController ` is your Protocol?

Comment: yes , ImagePickerController is protocol. @Enea Dume

Comment: now we need to see code where do you call `delegate. doneButtonDidPress`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Photo` framework to get imageName?

**See this example.**

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let asset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset {
            let assetResources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset)

            print(assetResources.first!.originalFilename)
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I have this for image picker.        extension PhotoViewController: ImagePickerDelegate {
    func doneButtonDidPress(_ imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
        self.image = images[0]
        let navigati:PhotoDescriptorController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.PhotoDescriptorController) as! PhotoDescriptorController
        navigati.imageDest = self.image
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigati, animated: true)
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @Enea Dume

Comment: you can change this an use  `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo `

Comment: also it's better to post your code, because we don't predict what methods have you use or how have you coded.

Comment: No, I have to do in this way. Please give answer in according to this codes. @Enea Dume

Answer (score 0):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let picURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        let imgData = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [picURL], options: nil)
        let asset = imgData.firstObject
        print(asset?.value(forKey: "filename"))

    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```